# python3-saml install fails in AppEngine Python 3.7 Standard

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I have a simple set-up in AppEngine Python 3.7 Standard with just two files: `requirements.txt` and `app.yaml`.

The `requirements.txt` file is:

```
Flask==1.0.2
python3-saml==1.4.1
```

The `app.yaml` file is:

```
runtime: python37
service: myservice
```

When I ran `gcloud app deploy`, I got the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build f8eaa62c-0385-4c1a-9788-b7765313ae08 status: FAILURE.
Build error details: {"message": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\n  Failed building wheel for xmlsec\nERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "code": 1, "type": "USER_ERROR"}.
```

Any ideas on how to work around this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Relevant portion from the Cloud Build logs:

```
Step #1 - "builder": Building wheels for collected packages: itsdangerous, xmlsec, MarkupSafe
Step #1 - "builder":   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for itsdangerous: started
Step #1 - "builder":   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for itsdangerous: finished with status 'done'
Step #1 - "builder":   Stored in directory: /tmp/tmpWitMY2/wheel
Step #1 - "builder":   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for xmlsec: started
Step #1 - "builder":   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for xmlsec: finished with status 'error'
Step #1 - "builder":   Complete output from command /env/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-wheel-o2h0m8_p/xmlsec/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-229ft_of:
Step #1 - "builder":   running bdist_wheel
Step #1 - "builder":   running build
Step #1 - "builder":   running build_ext
Step #1 - "builder":   *********************************************************************************
Step #1 - "builder":   Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed?
Step #1 - "builder":   *********************************************************************************
Step #1 - "builder":   
Step #1 - "builder":   ----------------------------------------
Step #1 - "builder":   Running setup.py clean for xmlsec
Step #1 - "builder":   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: started
Step #1 - "builder":   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
Step #1 - "builder":   Stored in directory: /tmp/tmpWitMY2/wheel
Step #1 - "builder": Successfully built itsdangerous MarkupSafe
Step #1 - "builder": Failed to build xmlsec
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder":   Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     pip_download_wheels took 6 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 9 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 9 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder":   Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": error: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
```

Comment: Do you already have a default service deployed?

Comment: @BrettJ Yes, there is a default service deployed (with first generation - Python 2.7 - runtime).

Answer (score 1):

The `python3-saml` package depends on [`xmlsec`](https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/), which is what's actually causing the build to fail here. [This package has pre-install dependencies on system-level libraries](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec#pre-install), hence this message in the logs:

> `Could not find xmlsec1 config. Are libxmlsec1-dev and pkg-config installed?`

It's not possible to install these system-level packages in the AppEngine Standard environment, instead you'll need to either use [a custom runtime with AppEngine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build), or use a replacement for `python3-saml` that does't have dependencies on system-level packages.